# XML parsing with PHP item keyword

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I have been trying to understand this following line of code for the past two hours. Please any explanation would be highly appreciated.

```
 $titleElement = $album->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
```

I am wondering how is this accessing the textNode of title? but not the first Title element.

The xml code and the corresponding php code is correct and displays the title correctly but I am not understanding as described above:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->load('albums.xml');

$collection = $doc->documentElement;
$albums = $collection->getElementsByTagName('album');

foreach ($albums as $album) {
    $titleElement = $album->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
    $year = $album->getAttribute('year');

    echo '<h1>Album: ';
    echo htmlspecialchars($titleElement->textContent) . '</h1>';

    echo '<div>Year: ';
    echo htmlspecialchars($year) . '</div>';
}

foreach($albums as $album){
    $oldest=9999;
    $year = $album->getAttribute('year');
    if($year<$oldest){

        $oldest=$year;
    }

}
echo "<h1> The oldest album is :"  . $oldest . "<h1>";

?>

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- File: albums.xml -->
<collection>
  <album year="2009">
    <title>Crack the Skye</title>
    <artist>Mastodon</artist>
  </album>
  <album year="1988">
    <title>South of Heaven</title>
    <artist>Slayer</artist>
  </album>
  <album year="1991">
    <title>Nevermind</title>
    <artist>Nirvana</artist>
  </album>
  <album year="1979">
    <title>London Calling</title>
    <artist>The Clash</artist>
  </album>
  <album year="1990">
    <title>Seasons in the Abyss</title>
    <artist>Slayer</artist>
  </album>
  <album year="1973">   
    <title>Raw Power</title>
    <artist>Iggy and The Stooges</artist>
  </album>
</collection>
```

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. It gets the correct one but not the first? First how? The code gets all `album` tags, then gets the first `title` tag for each of them and echos the text content of that.

Comment: no I meant that although the code is correct I am not understanding how is the item(0) working @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is it different than normal xml dom traversing for example:

album.getElementsByTagName("title").childNodes[0].nodeValue would have given me the correct title text.However

 $titleElement = $album->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
$titleElement->nodeValue     (This is correct-Why?)

Comment: Please any suggestions :(

Comment: I don’t understand your problem still. And what is “normal XML DOM traversing”? Why wouldn’t that be correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Are you asking about the difference between textContent and nodeValue?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  the confusion is because with javascript and ajax to traverse xml nodes these would be the steps
   var title=artist.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
   echo title[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

However in the problem, we arent accessing the text element node, but directly accesing the textNode like this

    artist.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]->nodeValue, 
and somehow this is working. My question is why?

Comment: @Gordon they are the same things if I am not wrong?, since I tried replacing textContent with nodeValue, and the answers were the same.

Comment: Because that’s how PHP does it. JavaScript is JavaScript, PHP is PHP

Comment: oh so they are different? got it then! Thank your for spending your time on it :)